# Android Cannot resolve constructor LineViewGraph

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, constructor, android-activity

I am trying to test this GraphView library inside a fragment. There is an error on this line `graphView = new LineGraphView(this, message);` as below:

> Cannot resolve constructor LineGraphView

Not sure how to reference the right context.

Here is a link to the example demos of the library.

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphviewdemos/SimpleGraph.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;


public class GraphFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static final GraphFragment newInstance(String message)
{
    GraphFragment f = new GraphFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graphfragment_layout, container, false);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

    GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphView.GraphViewData[] {
            new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
            , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
            , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
            , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
    });

    GraphView graphView;
    graphView = new LineGraphView(this, message);
    graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    layout.addView(graphView);

    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
 graphView = new LineGraphView(container.getContext(), message);
```

`Activity` extends `context` but fragments doesn't so whenever you try to attach a fragment to layout it's parent `ViewGroup` (in which fragment is displayed) is passed to onCreateView and you can get context out of it.